# Activate entry if child route is active in navigation

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have defined the following routes in my config. I only have one level in my main navigation and want to activate the navigation entry if a child route of the assigned navigation route gets matched. Is this possible?

In my example the navigation entry `Leads` should by active when I access any child route of the `lead` route (e.g. /lead/list). It should also work with deeper child routes (e.g. /lead/list/super/page).

**Routes**

```
'routes' => [
    'lead' => [
        'type' => Literal::class,

        'options' => [
            'route' => '/lead'
        ],

         'child_routes' => [
             'list' => [
                 'type' => Literal::class,
                 'may_terminate' => true,

                 'options' => [
                     'route' => '/list',

                     'defaults' => [
                         'controller' => Controller\Lead\ListController::class,
                         'action' => 'index'
                     ]
                 ]
             ],

             'view' => [
                 'type' => Segment::class,
                 'may_terminate' => true,

                 'options' => [
                     'route' => '/:id',

                     'defaults' => [
                         'controller' => Controller\Lead\ViewController::class,
                         'action' => 'index'
                     ]
                 ]
             ]
         ]
     ]
]
```

**Navigation**

```
'default' => [
    'lead' => [
        'label' => 'Leads',
        'route' => 'lead',
    ]
]
```

Comment: You would need to write your own version of the zf2 navigation helper. The current one requires it's own config. (Like the answer below mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your navigation list in same way like you defined routes.
**Routes**

```
      'navigation' => [
            'type'    => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/navigation',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'child' => [
                    'type' => Literal::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/child',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                            'action' => 'index'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => [
                        'child' => [
                            'type' => Literal::class,
                            'options' => [
                                'route' => '/child',
                                'defaults' => [
                                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                                    'action' => 'index'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ],
```

**Navigation**

```
return [
    'navigation' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Navigation',
                'route' => 'navigation',
                'pages' => [
                    [
                        'label' => 'Child #1',
                        'route' => 'navigation/child',
                        'pages' => [
                            [
                                'label' => 'Child #2',
                                'route' => 'navigation/child/child',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'navigation' => Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now, when you access:
`/naviation` - only navigation is active
`/navigation/child` - navigation and child are active
`/navigation/child/child` - navigation, child and child are active

If you want render only active branch you can use in your view

`<?= $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true); ?>`

Or if you want to customize a bit menu you can use `renderMenu()` method which accepts 2 paramaters. `$container` and `$options` so you can add your own class or set indent for menu.

You can also use `renderPartial()` and render menu based on provided partial

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I don't want to do, because I have to configure the whole navigation with all child routes and only need the first level in my navigation :)

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will not be able to do this. Zend set active elements based on items in navigation config. So if you don't want to define static configuration, then you can attach to route event and create navigation dynamically, but as far as I know you will have to create navigation anyway if you want to use this helper